# items.IndexOf not printing out position

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I am fairly new to C# programming and have just finished learning about placeholders and the great convenience of the `Array` libraries/methods that can be used in C#.

I have written a very simple program that start with a populated array list of 3 strings. I have everything correct, as far as I know, but for whatever reason my `items.IndexOf()` method is only and always printing out `0` into the console.

Can anyone tell/teach me as to why this may be happening? As far as I know a `foreach` statement should update the values of the array so each pass through the `items.IndexOf()` value should change but it is not.

Here is my short code and I appreciate any advice, tips and help!

---

```
namespace ConsoleApplication01
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] items = { "sword", "shield", "potion" };

        WriteLine("Quick! You're being attacked by a Goblin Bruiser!");
        WriteLine("Which item will you use?");

        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            WriteLine("{0} {1}",items.IndexOf(item), item);
        }

        ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:
The issue was they syntax of `items.IndexOf` and `Array.IndexOf`.
I assumed that because my items variable was an array it could be used in the way my code below shows. Thank you for all of the people who have taught me !**

Comment: read this carefully: `item.IndexOf(item)` :)

Comment: Double check your usage of `IndexOf` to see if you can spot the error. Also, I would recommend stepping through the debugger to shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! I have tried this `items.IndexOf(item)` and get a red line error under the IdexOf() method that says it only accepts 1 arguement :/

Comment: `items.IndexOf` and `Array.IndexOf` are two different methods with different syntax; which one are you using?

Comment: I would like to point out that I do not believe my question was "off topic" at all. @Blorgbeard the answers given even had issues with the syntax of this. I was simply trying to learn and I still do not exactly understand why items (my array) will not work like `items.IndexOf()` and instead I need `Array.IndexOf();` I asked the question only to learn and I just feel putting it on hold was odd :/

Comment: The reason people put your question on hold is because the code you are using and the code you posted are different. This confuses people and makes the answers nonsensical. If you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38254731/edit) your question to fix this it can be taken off hold.

Comment: @DourHighArch are you referring to me saying my `Array.IndexOf()` ? I was using that method but using in a way with my items.indexOf. Items is my array that was my question. It was not wrong it was my own confusion. I can fix this but it misses my entire question :/

Comment: Your title and prose still says `Array.IndexOf()` and the code still says `items.IndexOf()` even after your edits. If you fix this your question can be taken off hold.

Comment: @DourHighArch thank you - i have fixed the post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have your variables mixed up

it should be `items` not `item` in the for loop. like this :

```
foreach (string item in items)
{
    WriteLine("{0} {1}", Array.IndexOf(items,item), item);
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing and have tried it but it does not work :/. It throws a red line under the `items.IndexOf` and says it only accepts 1 arguement

Comment: then you have a typo - show the new corrected code in the question

Comment: I will post the new code! Thank you all :)

Comment: I have update my answer to use Array.IndexOf instead

Comment: Is there a reason as to why items.IndexOf will not work ? Also this works now! Thank you for teaching me!

Comment: IndexOf will work directly if items were a list not an array

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I am unsure as to why my question has been put on hold but I do not see as to how it was an irrelevant question. Thank you !